# Installing experimental Scribus dev version (1.5svn) via Homebrew package manager

Tags: svn, homebrew

Running OS X 10.8.5 with Homebrew v0.9.5

The brew formula I'm using is from a gist, based on a Scribus wiki page called Scribus_and_Homebrew. (I can't post the link because I don't have enough rep.)

```
require 'formula'

  class ScribusDev < Formula
  head 'svn://scribus.net//trunk/Scribus', :using => :svn
  depends_on 'cmake' => :build
  depends_on 'little-cms2'
  # Install Qt5 beforehand and link to it via CMAKE below
  # depends_on 'qt5'
  depends_on 'cairo'
  depends_on 'jpeg'
  depends_on 'libtiff'
  depends_on 'libart'
  depends_on 'fontconfig'
  depends_on 'openssl'
  depends_on 'pkg-config' => :build
  depends_on 'python'
  depends_on 'hunspell'
  # zlib on 10.8.5 is not up to date enough hence the following:
  depends_on 'homebrew/dupes/zlib'
  depends_on 'ghostscript' => :recommended
  depends_on 'graphicsmagick' => :recommended
  depends_on 'boost' => :recommended
  depends_on 'poppler' => :recommended
  # depends_on 'podofo' => :recommended

  def install
    system "cmake", ".", "-DBUILD_OSX_BUNDLE=1", "-DWANT_CAIRO=1", "-DWANT_HUNSPELL=1", "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=#{prefix}/ScribusDev.app/Contents/", "-DUSE_QT5=1","-DWITH_PODOFO=1", "-DQT_PREFIX=~/Qt/5.3/clang_64"
                    # Change ~/Qt/x.y.z/clang_64 based on what version Qt you have installed
                    # "-DWANT_SCRIPTER2=1",
    system "make"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

How I understand the issue is that Cmake is complaining about the temporary build directory that is created by the Homebrew svn checkout process.

```
[  1%] [  1%] Generating moc_unzip_p.cpp
Generating moc_storytext.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target scribus_wpg_lib
[  1%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/wpg/CMakeFiles/scribus_wpg_lib.dir/WPG1Parser.cpp.o
[  1%] Generating moc_zip_p.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target scribus_2geom_lib
[  1%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/wpg/CMakeFiles/scribus_wpg_lib.dir/WPG2Parser.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target scribus_text_lib

SKIPPING....

[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Encoder.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/PGFimage.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libscribus_zip_lib.a
[  2%] Built target scribus_zip_lib
Scanning dependencies of target svnheader
[  2%] Generating svn_header, svnheader.h
-- Found Subversion: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/svn (found version "1.7.10") 
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindSubversion.cmake:83 (message):
  Command "/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/svn info /tmp/scribus-dev-MsPz/scribus"
  failed with output:

  svn: E155007: '/tmp/scribus-dev-MsPz/scribus' is not a working copy

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /tmp/scribus-dev-MsPz/cmake/modules/getsvn.cmake:4 (Subversion_WC_INFO)


make[2]: *** [scribus/svn_header] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scribus/CMakeFiles/svnheader.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/PGFstream.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/text/CMakeFiles/scribus_text_lib.dir/fsize.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/text/CMakeFiles/scribus_text_lib.dir/frect.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Subband.cpp.o

SKIPPING...

[  4%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/lib2geom/CMakeFiles/scribus_2geom_lib.dir/solve-bezier-one-d.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/lib2geom/CMakeFiles/scribus_2geom_lib.dir/solve-bezier-parametric.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/lib2geom/CMakeFiles/scribus_2geom_lib.dir/scribushelper.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libscribus_2geom_lib.a
[  4%] Built target scribus_2geom_lib
make: *** [all] Error 2

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
HEAD: be34fbb6eb43f26455b36f1770ce26674f08ee81
CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.8.5-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
```

I'm still working to fully understand that cmake is now looking for revision based svn checkout. How do I tell homebrew to do this?

(All Homebrew Logs can be found at https://gist.github.com/luzpaz/9042115)

Answer (score 0):

Subversion needed a new Download Strategy. The formula has been altered. Replace the top 4 lines of the above formula with these lines below:

```
require 'formula'

class ScribusDownloadStrategy < SubversionDownloadStrategy
  def stage
    FileUtils.cp_r @clone.children, '.'
  end
end


class ScribusDev < Formula
  head 'svn://scribus.net//trunk/Scribus', :using => ScribusDownloadStrategy
```